# Effect of ARP table changing during/in-between send() calls

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, arp

Following on from [an issue we're having](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263450/legal-arp-poisoning-by-machine-aggregating-2-nics-crashes-us), I'm trying to understand the effect/impact of the ARP table changing when a process is busily writing data (thousands of UDP video packets + occasional TCP messages) out on a socket using repeated calls to `send()`.

It seems that, for whatever reason, our process (more accurately: Live555 WIS-Streamer's process) is tripped up / blocked by this event.

Can anyone help me understand what is likely to happen in this scenario - what errors / return states we might expect/catch from `send()`, how we can mitigate this in our code?

I am currently reading through the informational pamphlet entitled `Understanding Linux network Internals` (a mere 1035 pages) but any hints to help accelerate the debugging process greatly appreciated!

**Edit to add:** I don't want people to think I'm ignoring questions about port states or process states, the issue happens very rarely (average maybe once per 24h) and only on one (remote) installation that we can't easily get access to, we're trying hard to replicate it in the lab so we can do more detailed diagnostics but the system watchdog resets within ~3 mins of the problem occurring, so by the time the news reaches us it's already rebooted and started working OK.

**Edit to add Wireshark info**:
I'm not sure the best way to summarise wireshark captures here (very hard to upload ~1Tb of captured packets!) but I'll try. `Cam:X` & `Cam:Y` are two streams of RTSP video streamed by two identical instances of Live555 WIS Streamer from different ports. Server 'A' and 'B' are the MACs of the two NICs on the server.

The sequence of packets goes like this:

```
UDP Packet from Cam:X -> Server 'A'
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'A'
UDP Packet from Cam:X -> Server 'A'
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'A'
UDP Packet from Cam:X -> Server 'A'
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'A'
ARP Packet to Cam from Server 'B' "<my IP> is now on 'B'"
Intel ANS Probe broadcast from Server 'B', Sender ID '1' team ID 'B'
Intel ANS Probe broadcast from Server 'A', Sender ID '2' team ID 'B'
<silence> from Cam:X
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'B'
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'B'
UDP Packet from Cam:Y -> Server 'B'
```

There are no other packets in the stream at or around this time. The Intel ANS packets do not always coincide with the ARPs from the NIC but I thought I'd include them for the sake of completeness.

The issue seems to be VERY sensitive to timing, we see these "team" ARPs regularly from the server and only once in a blue moon do they cause us an issue - as if there's a particular point in the network stack code that's sensitive to the ARP table changing. It's not always the same stream instance that falls over, and notably the other instance (as well as all other net traffic - HTTP etc.) continues to work fine.

It sounds like teamed NICs "should not" ARP like this mid-session, but of course they won't be aware of any session when the traffic is all UDP.

Comment: Is it a `blocking` or `non-blocking` socket? Can you run `strace` on the process that is blocked to check where it is blocked?

Comment: Potentially it could be either as the streamer does both UDP + TCP sends depending on whether it's sending a video packet (UDP) or a control message (TCP). The system is an embedded one running busybox so we don't have strace available.

Comment: if you are doing send on TCP or UDP sockets it would work with two different sockets created, unless you are using raw sockets or you have a modified stack which can handle both at the same time(not that I am aware of any).Both of these sockets should either be blocking or non-blocking. 
I recommend starting with a good socket guide as this one
http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/syscalls.html#sendrecv
or netstat -atp(tcp) or netstat -aup(udp) to check which sockets are open for your process and the state of each

Comment: please paste your server network configuration. `ip add` on linux or `ipconfig /all` on windows

Comment: It's a small embedded Busybox install, we don't have the `ip` command - yes, it's REALLY frustrating! We have `netstat` and `ifconfig`...

Comment: send() isn't going to give you any error code/return state - unless the ARP fails (times out, because of no reply). What you might experience are lost packets while ARP is in progress if you're using non-blocking sockets, or the network drops packets if it's in an inconsistent state, or that your send() call itself blocks while ARP is in progress if you use blocking sockets. In addition, you'll experience time delays while ARP is in progress, as packets are held in memory instead of being transmitted, However it sounds like you have a networking issue more than a programming issue.

Comment: Agreed the cause seems to be the teamed NICs, but from our end of things we'd really like to "idiot proof" our system so it can't get tripped over by stuff like this - hence trying to understand where in the kernel network stack / stdlib things could be going awry. It may be some mis-configuration in our kernel build, tweaking params, passing different args to socket/send commands... we're several layers down from where we started and VERY reluctant to tweak kernel code without VERY good reason & solid understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well if only to give some [closure](https://xkcd.com/979/) to this the customer reconfigured their dodgy network card and everything worked, so unfortunately for the curious that means no-one is going to pay anyone to look too closely at what could've been done to fix that case.